# Debian, kill java by it's jar name?

Tags: php, ssh, debian, java

Okay, I am going to be running two java application on the same VPS one will be running nearly all the time. The other one will not need to be. I am wondering if there is away to kill java based on it's jar name also this will be done via php using Net/SSH2

currently echo $ssh->exec('killall -e java'); but this will kill the other java application as well

Answer (score 2):

There are so many options for how to do this.

My recommendation is to use the `-f` flag from `pkill` to search through the process name for your `.jar` file.

For example:

```
pkill -9 -f my-application.jar
```

This will search through the process name for `my-application.jar`.

**ETA:**

You can also test what processes will be grabbed by using `pgrep`. `pgrep` is the sister command to `pkill` and accepts most of the same CLI flags, but instead of killing the command, it just prints info about the match.

In your case you would run

```
pgrep -f my-application.jar
```

And see if it returns your application's PID.